# How to push all the documents in a collection with values to another collection in form of map firestore web

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have products in my cart which on checkout get converted to orders. I want all the documents in cart collection to be mapped as an object map / array in orders collection inside a single document.

```
function placeOrder(){
    var uid = auth.currentUser.uid
    db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('carts')
    .get().then((items)=>{
        items.forEach((item)=>{
            var item_key = item.id
           db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('orders').doc().set({
               items : [item_key]
           })
           db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('carts').doc(item_key).delete()
        })       
    })
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: It looks like this code runs doc().set() in a loop, creating a doc for each cart item. (each of those docs will contain a single-element array).  I think the text states you want to create a single doc per user.  If you start with the objective of pulling that set out of the forEach loop, you'll end up writing correct code.  Move the delete even later, after everything else is done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Order item IDs => Array field:

```
...
.get()
.then(snapshot => {
    const ids = snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.id)

    db.collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .collection('orders')
        .doc()
        .set({items : ids})
}
```

### Order item data => Sub-Collection:

```
...
.get()
.then(snapshot => {
    const batch = db.batch()
    const orderRef = db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('orders').doc()
    const cartRef = db.collection('users').doc(uid).collection('carts').doc(item_key)

    batch.set(orderRef, { 
        // order fields
    })

    snapshot.forEach(docSnap => {
        batch.set(orderRef.collection('order_items').doc(docSnap.id), {
            // order item fields
        })
    })

    batch.delete(cartRef)
    batch.commit()
}
```

Comment: @ShrinivasBendkhale - Sorry; I forgot that items is actually a snapshot. I'm a Kotlin dev moonlighting JS! Should be fixed already.

Comment: This was working for me. I need the data also inside the document as a mapped object

Comment: I believe that in Firestore you can only have Map<primitive, primitive> (where key and value are number, String, perhaps some other Firestore types like GeoPoint). I don't think you can have a field that is Map<X, Object>. You need to use a subcollection.

Comment: for example: how to map object with values inside document for example a document id storing values of product name, product id, product price, etc ...

Comment: I think you can only do this with a sub-collection. I've updated the answer.